# android greenDao - upon query using generated Get function

Tags: android, greendao

upon query using generated Get function - I'm getting the following list of entity
[null]

how could it be?

Comment: Your question provides too little information. Please get familiar on how to ask questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: The Get is querying the database - meaning is't try to get entity according to its Id(which is the PK). I don't ask for you to find a bug in my code or explain to me how to use GreenDao. I know that already. The question is how such thing could happen(sql meaning). Hope it clear